# Topology book with tilt towards differential geometry

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, book-recommendation

I've studied some differential geometry and would like to start reading through some more advanced texts on the subject but they all require knowledge of topology which I haven't taken a course in.

Can anyone recommend a good introductory book in topology that is biased toward a future study of differential geometry (or even algebraic geometry)?  So it should cover things like manifolds and fibre bundles.  I know the standard reference is Munkres's *Topology* but taking a look at the index I didn't see anything on fibre/ vector/ tangent bundles so I don't think that's what I'd want.  What are your recommendations, math.SE?

Comment: Bredon? It is quite concise in the topology part, though.

Comment: Perhaps you want a text on *differential* topology, like Guillemin and Pollack?

Comment: As someone who studies topology or differential geometry or something like that: you should really just learn the point-set topology from a standard source. If you want something manifoldy, you can read Lee's topological manifolds book or Kinsey's topology of surfaces (though be warned that this latter book's definition of topology is wrong! Somehow this is only a minor error because I can still recommend the book.)